# Where can i find a EC2 Oracle database 11gR2 AMI?

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g

Does anyone know where i can find such a AMI? Oracle database Enterprise Edition 11g release 2?

Has oracle supplied it somewhere or has someone else created one i can use?

Comment: Good point, I will move this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS site has a number of AMIs for Oracle 11g servers. [Find them here](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/oracle/).

There's no pre-canned images for 12c, for whatever reason.